# Repositories in domain driven design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I've been struggling with DDD for several months now and, while I think I have a reasonably good idea about some of the concepts I'm less confident about how implementation should work, specifically how I should load data from the database.  It doesn't help that I've only been working in C# (spottily) for six months.

[ORIGINAL QUESTION - SEE UPDATE BELOW]

> In the app I've started working on, I have a domain namespace that contains base classes, a service namespace that performs operations using those base class, and then a repository and DAL namespace to connect to the database.
>
> I thought the easiest way to proceed would be to use inheritance in the service namespace to add procedures like LoadFromDb, but when I start implementing I'm finding that this method typically requires the most code because I have to assign all the class properties twice (once in the repository namespace and then in the service namespace).
>
> Here's an example.  I can get Option 2 and Option 3 to work, but I was hoping for something closer in spirit to Option 1.

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Request
    {
        public int RequestID{get; set;}
        public string RequestingUser {get; set;}
        public string Title {get; set;}
        public string Description{get; set;}
        public string status {get; set;}
    }
}


namespace app
{
    class MyApp
    {
        void Main()
        {
            //option 1
            Domain.Request x = new Service.svcRequest(5);

            //option 2
            Domain.Request y = new Service.svcRequest(5);

            //option 3
            Domain.Request z = new Domain.Request();
            Service.svcRequest2.loadRequest(5, z);
        }
    }
}

namespace Service
{
    public class svcRequest : Domain.Request
    {
        public svcRequest(int RequestID)
        {
            //this is what I want to do.  
            //  It fails because "this" is read-only 
            //  and because "this" can't be implicitly converted to DomainRequest.
            this = (Domain.Request)repos.Loads.LoadRequest(RequestID);

            //option 2, which is what I'm doing instead for now, but when you get 
            //  to 20 or 50 properties, it's a bit much, 
            //  esp. since those properties have already been assigned once 
            //  within the repository namespace.
            Domain.Request MyRequest = repos.Loads.LoadRequest(RequestID);
            this.RequestID = MyRequest.RequestID;
            this.RequestingUser = MyRequest.RequestingUser;
            this.Title = MyRequest.Title;
            this.Description = MyRequest.Description;
            this.status = MyRequest.status;
        }
    }

    public class svcRequest2
    {
        //option 3.  Much less code, but now I'm not really using inheritance, 
        //  so in my application layer I can't just declare my variable 
        //  and use the svcRequest constructor
        public static void loadRequest(int RequestID, Domain.Request MyRefRequest)
        {
            MyRefRequest = (Domain.Request)repos.Loads.LoadRequest(RequestID);
        }
    }
}

namespace repos
{
    public static class Loads
    {
        public static Domain.Request LoadRequest(int RequestID)
        {
            Domain.Request MyRequest = new Domain.Request();
            DataRow MyRow = dal.Loads.LoadRequestRow(RequestID);
            MyRequest.RequestID = RequestID;
            MyRequest.RequestingUser = (string)MyRow["User"];
            MyRequest.Title = (string)MyRow["Title"];
            MyRequest.Description = (string)MyRow["Description"];
            MyRequest.status = (string)MyRow["Status"];
            return MyRequest;
        }
    }
}

namespace dal
{
    public static class Loads
    {
        public static DataRow LoadRequestRow(int RequestID)
        {
            OleDbConnection dbCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=dbServer;Initial Catalog=RequestDB;User ID=Joe;Password=password");
            string Select = "Select * from RequestTable where ID = " + RequestID;
            OleDbDataAdapter dbRequest = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select, dbCon);
            DataSet dsRequest = new DataSet();
            dbRequest.Fill(dsRequest);
            DataRow drRequest = dsRequest.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            return drRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]
Here's a second try.  I renamed my Domain namespace to Model, and renamed my Service namespace to Domain, which I think more closely fits the DDD conventions.  As suggested, I added an interface in the repository namespace that I used in the DAL.  The only thing I can't get to work right now is option 1's Load statement, but I think I just need to research inheritance a bit more.

Am I getting closer?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Model
{
    public class Request
    {
        public int RequestID{get; set;}
        public string RequestingUser {get; set;}
        public string Title {get; set;}
        public string Description{get; set;}
        public string status {get; set;}
    }
}


namespace App
{
    class MyApp
    {
        void Main()
        {
            //option 1
            Model.Request x = new Domain.dmnRequest(5);

            //option 2
            Model.Request y = new Domain.dmnRequest2(5);

            //option 3
            Model.Request z = new Model.Request();
            Domain.dmnRequest3.loadRequest(5, z);
        }
    }
}

namespace Domain
{
    public class dmnRequest : Model.Request, dal.Request
    {
        public dmnRequest(int requestID)
        {
            //this is what I want to do.  I'm not sure why it's failing
            Load(requestID); 
        }
    }

    public class dmnRequest2 : Model.Request
    {
        public dmnRequest2(int requestID) 
        {
            //option 2; it works but is cumbersome after you hit the 20th property
            dal.Request tmpRequest = new dal.Request();
            tmpRequest.Load(requestID);
            this.RequestID = tmpRequest.RequestID;
            this.RequestingUser = tmpRequest.RequestingUser;
            this.Title = tmpRequest.Title;
            this.Description = tmpRequest.Description;
            this.status = tmpRequest.status;
        }
    }

    public class dmnRequest3
    {
        //option 3.  Much less code, but now I'm not really using inheritance, so in my application layer I can't just declare my variable and use the dmnRequest constructor
        public static void loadRequest(int RequestID, Model.Request MyRequest)
        {
            dal.Request dalRequest = (dal.Request)MyRequest;
            dalRequest.Load(RequestID);
            MyRequest = (Model.Request)dalRequest;
        }
    }
}

namespace repos
{
    public interface SaveMe {void Save(int ID); }
    public interface LoadMe {void Load(int ID); }
}

namespace dal
{
    public class Request : Model.Request, repos.LoadMe
    {
        public void Load(int requestID)
        {
            OleDbConnection dbCon = new OleDbConnection("yaddayadda");
            string Select = "Select * from RequestTable where ID = " + requestID.ToString();
            OleDbDataAdapter dbRequest = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select, dbCon);
            DataSet dsRequest = new DataSet();
            dbRequest.Fill(dsRequest);
            DataRow drRequest = dsRequest.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            this.RequestID = requestID;
            this.RequestingUser = (string)drRequest["User"];
            this.Title = (string)drRequest["Title"];
            this.Description = (string)drRequest["Description"];
            this.status = (string)drRequest["Status"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You got it all wrong. In DDD things are pretty simple. The Domain knows only about the repository *interface* which gets implemented by an actually repository class in the Persistence Layer (DAL). The repository works with the database to save/load domain objects (in DDD those domain objects should be aggregate roots).

Nothing should be static here and the repository should get all the data it needs from the db and then use that to restore an object. The repository ALWAYS returns a Domain Entity, never a data row, data table, Entity Framework entities etc. That's because the purpose of the Repository is to decouple the Domain from the persistence details.

Simply put, the Domain just says: "Hey repository give me that BsuinessEntity with this id". The Domain tells the repository what to get and never *how* to get it. The domain doesn't really know there is a database involved. All it sees it's an abstraction (the repository interface) working with objects the Domain knows about.

The point of all this is to respect the Separation of Concerns. The Domain cares about business concepts and use cases, while the repository cares about storing/retrieving objects from the db.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You gave me a lot to think about.